# A word for a person or group of people that are always in search of something or someone. Kind of like a fanatic

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word to describe the act of always to be on the outlook for a specific object or idea. My character is really compulsive when it comes to symmetry. He is always trying to find the perfect symmetrical correspondent for what he needs... Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For a book or what?

Answer (score 1):

A word that comes to mind is "Seeker"

> Seeker; a person who is attempting to find or obtain something.

I think putting it as "Fanatical seeker" gives the appropriate impression.

Comment: The OP asked about the act, not about the person doing the act. According to your choice, the action could be termed "fanatical/frantic search/pursuit".

Comment: @Gustavson Well that's just wonderful then, his question is different in the title and in the body. Guess my answer gets 1/2 and your comment, the remainder.

Comment: You are right there. However, I always pay more attention to the body. Titles -- even titles of papers, books, or even headlines -- can be misleading.

Comment: The act is a *quest*.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the word is "obsession". In medical terms, it could be a case of OCD (obsessive compulsive disorder). Here is a description of the disorder when it applies to always looking for symmetry: http://www.ocdtypes.com/symmetry-ocd.php